# jquery post multiple submit errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i have a big problem , im trying to build a website around the `one page template system` so hear is how it works..... a user clicks a link: `<a href="#" id="<? md5('....').'-link-stay' ?>">.....</a>` but the problem is i have more then 100 php generated links on one page that is attached to a listener and for some strange reason, every time a link gets clicked, and a user returns back to the main page it doubles the request....
in other words : a user click links.... go to a page ..... and he see's a ton of links.... the user clicks a link..... go to a page. but if a user goes back the ajax call doubles????
ex. 1 post , ... 2 post ..... 4 post.... 8 post ..... 16 post..... 32 post ...... 64 post.....
im trying to debug with chrome, and it shows how many post to the `network(HTTP Request)` that are made every time one has been called and it shows how many post being made and its doubling

Html Markup :

```
    <script>
    // main menu
    $('header a').addClass('lvl1Links');
    // classifeds
    $('#9090 a').addClass('lvl1Links');
    //states - citys - cats ads
    $('#selectable a').addClass('lvl1Links');
    // re-install link management
    $(function(){
        $('.lvl1Links').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('pload').html('<img src="source/image/lbl.gif">');
            var page = $(this).attr('id');
            var huh = $('input:hidden').val();
            var data = 'pop='+huh+'&page='+page;
            $.post('source/php/bots/authorize.php',data,function(data){
                    $('#pager_master_div').html(data).slideDown();
                    $('pload').html('');
                });
        });
    });
    // speacial style on  certain input boxes
    $('input').addClass('input');
    $('#op').removeClass('input');
    $('#sp').removeClass('input');
    $('button').button();
    //$("#BUser_Home_Wrapper a .lvl1Links").removeClass("lvl1Links");
    </script><div id="9090"><ol id="selectable"><li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="contr"><a  href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alabama:1">Alabama</a></div><div class="citys"><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alabama:1.Birmingham:1">Birmingham</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alabama:1.Montgomery:2">Montgomery</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alabama:1.Mobile:3">Mobile</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alabama:1.Huntsville:4">Huntsville</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alabama:1.Tuscaloosa:5">Tuscaloosa</a><br><li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="contr"><a  href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alaska:2">Alaska</a></div><div class="citys"><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alaska:2.Anchorage:6">Anchorage</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alaska:2.Juneau:7">Juneau</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alaska:2.Fairbanks:8">Fairbanks</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alaska:2.Sitka:9">Sitka</a><br><a href="#" id="d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d.class.Alaska:2.Ketchikan:10">Ketchikan</a><br></ol></div><style>
    .contr{

    }
    .citys{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        height:110px;
        width:100px;
        top:30px;
        left:-5%;
        right:-5%;
        z-index:100;
        background:#FFF;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:5px #0099FF solid;
        font-size:10px;
    }
    .cityz{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        height:200;
        width:100px;
        top:-100px;
        left:-5%;
        right:-5%;
        z-index:100;
        background:#FFF;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:5px #0099FF solid;
        font-size:10px;
    }
    .citys a{
    font-size:15px;     
    }
    .cityz a{
    font-size:15px;     
    }
    #selectable li a{
    font-size:14px;
    }
    #selectable li city a{

    }
    #selectable {
        list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;  
    }
    #selectable li {
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding: 1px;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;

    text-align: center;
     }
    </style>
    <script>
         $('.ui-state-default').mouseenter(function(e) {
                $('.citys', this).slideDown(); // added this 
            }).mouseleave(function(e) {
                $('.citys', this).toggle(); // added this 
            });
        // bttom rows
         $('.ui-state-default').mouseenter(function(e) {
                $('.cityz', this).slideDown(); // added this 
            }).mouseleave(function(e) {
                $('.cityz', this).toggle(); // added this 
            });


    </script>

    <results></results><input type="hidden" id="fortknox" name="fortknox" value="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b"><results></results><input type="hidden" id="fortknox" name="fortknox" value="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b">
        <script>
        $('input').addClass('input');

        $('button').button();
// click event for all links 
$(function(){
    $('.lvl1Links').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('pload').html('<img src="source/image/lbl.gif">');
        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        var huh = $('input:hidden').val();
        var data = 'pop='+huh+'&page='+page;
        $.post('source/php/bots/authorize.php',data,function(data){
                $('#pager_master_div').html(data).slideDown();
                $('pload').html('');
            });
    });
}); 

</script>
```

php code:

```
<?
case 'class':
require('functions/cats.php');
classie($p);
break;

function classie($p){
    connect();
    $state = explode(':',$p[2]);
    $total = count($state);
    $s = md5('?').'.class.';
    $sid  = $state[1];
    $state = $state[0];
    echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"$s$state:$sid\">$state</a>";
    echo "<ol id=\"selectable\">";
    if(isset($p[3])){
        $city = explode(':',$p[3]); 
        $cid  = $city[1];
        $city = $city[0];
        echo " : <a href=\"#\" id=\"$s$state:$sid.$city:$cid\">$city</a>";
        $sqlca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE `cityId`= ".$cid." ");
            while($rowsy = mysql_fetch_array($sqlca)){
        echo " : <a href=\"#\" id=\"$s$state:$sid.".$city.":".$cid.".".$rowsy['name'].":".$rowsy['id']."\">".$rowsy['name']."</a>";
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: try using 'on' rather than 'click' to avoid this behavior: $('.lvl1Links').on('click', function(event) { .....

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your problem using unbind click to prevent double clicking and causing 
        multiple entry. Take a look my revision about your code on JS below:

```
   $(function(){
        $('.lvl1Links').bind(''click,function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('pload').html('<img src="source/image/lbl.gif">');
        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        var huh = $('input:hidden').val();
        var data = 'pop='+huh+'&page='+page;
         $.post('source/php/bots/authorize.php',data,function(data){
            $('#pager_master_div').html(data).slideDown();
            $('pload').html('');
        });
        $(this).unbind(event);
    });
 });
```